# How to turn a string value into a function call on a class from another class, in Python?

Tags: python, class, eval

I first converted a string of a method name, to a method with eval. Now I want to call that method on a class, but I'm having trouble.

```
method = eval(request.args['method']) 
Communicator.method
```

`eval(request.args['method'])` returns the method, however calling this line in this class throws an error, as the method is not defined in this class. The method belongs to another class "Communicator", so I'm trying to call the method on Communicator directly.

For example would need something like `Communicator.method` however defining `method` above throws an error, and so does calling `Communicator.eval(method)`

Is there a "call" method that lets you call a method on a class by passing the method name into another "call" method, such as `Communicator.call(post_create())`?

I also noticed that `Communicator.__dict__` has references to all its methods, so maybe I could call it somehow that way?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Assuming you have an instance of `Communicator` named `communicator`, you could get the method with `getattr(communicator, "method_name_here")`

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks so much for the help! Now I'm trying to turn the arguments from a string, into a dict. For example `'{'latitutude': '31'}` -> `{'latitude':'31'}` . I tried using eval() but the issue is that it also turned the key and value from strings into variables, but I want those to stay as strings. Do you know how I can do this? thanks!!

Comment: You can use `json.loads()` for this, if the inner quote marks are double-quotes.  `json.loads('{"a": 1}')`